# Drag and Drop between QTreeWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-and-drop, qtreewidget

Is it possible two drag and drop items between two QTreeWidgets? I have one tree-widget Tree1 and a second one Tree2. Tree1 is somehow the master which contains all elements (only top-level elements, child elements are disabled). Only sorting should be possible (no edit, move, copy etc.). Tree2 should contain items which are added by drag and drop from Tree1. The idea is that if one item gets moved from Tree1 to Tree2, it gets removed from Tree1. In Tree2, items can be moved (nothing more).

I have already checked the internet but could not really find a solution. I tried to override the drag and drop methods of the QTreeWidget class, but I do not understand the drag-drop mechanism at the moment. I do not see any event if I drag an item form Tree1 to Tree2.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source()==self:
            super().dropEvent(event)
        elif isinstance(event.source(), TreeWidget):
            print(True)

def create_treeWidget_1():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "y1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "y2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "y3")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "z1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "z2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "z3")
    
    return treeWidget

def create_treeWidget_2():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "a")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "b")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "c")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "3")
    
    return treeWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    tree1=create_treeWidget_1()
    tree2=create_treeWidget_2()
    tree1.show()
    tree2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

09172023 Update: I continued with my project. Now I am faced with a new problem which is related to the initial question. So I think it fits perfectly to this thread. See below the updated code which solves the initial problem and includes the new one.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    

class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):

    itemDropped=QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self)
        
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super().dropEvent(event)

        if event.source() is not self:
            item=self.itemAt(event.pos())
            
            if self.dropIndicatorPosition()==self.BelowItem:
                item=self.itemBelow(item)
                
            elif self.dropIndicatorPosition()==self.OnViewport:
                item=self.topLevelItem(self.topLevelItemCount()-1)

            item.setFlags(item.flags()&~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)

        self.itemDropped.emit()


def create_treeWidget_1():
    treeWidget=QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)
    
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "y1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "y2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "y3")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "z1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "z2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "z3")
    
    return treeWidget


def create_treeWidget_2():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)

    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)

    treeWidget.itemDropped.connect(updateView)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "a")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "b")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "c")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "3")
    
    return treeWidget


def create_treeWidget_3():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)

    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)

    treeWidget.itemDropped.connect(updateView)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")
    
    return treeWidget


def updateView():
    try:
        print('update')
        print('    update left:')
            
        iterator=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree2)

        while iterator.value():
            item=iterator.value()
            for column in range(item.columnCount()): print('        '+item.text(column))
            print()
            iterator+=1
            
        print('\n    update right:')
        iterator=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree3)

        while iterator.value():
            item=iterator.value()
            for column in range(item.columnCount()): print('        '+item.text(column))
            print()
            iterator+=1

        print()

        print('-----')
    except BaseException as e: print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    tree1=create_treeWidget_1()
    tree2=create_treeWidget_2()
    tree3=create_treeWidget_3()
    tree1.show()
    tree2.show()
    tree3.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I added a third tree widget called Tree3. Everytime an item is moved from Tree2 to Tree3 or vice versa a signal gets emited. The idea is that every time items get moved the new distribution of the items between Tree2 and Tree3 is collected. But for some rease if an item gets moved the tree which owned the item does not gets updated.

Example: Move item from Tree2 to Tree3. The screen output shows that the item appears in Tree2 and in Tree3. If the signal gets emitted again by moving an item internally (inside Tree2 or Tree3) the item is removed in Tree2. I think the content of Tree2 is not really updated when the drop event emits the signal. Is there an additional event which appears when Tree2 is updated that can be used to emit the signal?

09252023 Solution:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

counter=0

class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    
    itemDropped=QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self)       
        
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super().dropEvent(event)

        if event.source() is not self:
            item=self.itemAt(event.pos())
            
            if self.dropIndicatorPosition()==self.BelowItem:
                item=self.itemBelow(item)
                
            elif self.dropIndicatorPosition()==self.OnViewport:
                item=self.topLevelItem(self.topLevelItemCount()-1)

            item.setFlags(item.flags()&~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)

        self.itemDropped.emit()

def create_treeWidget_1():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)
    
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "y1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "y2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "y3")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "z1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "z2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "z3")

    treeWidget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(buffer)
    
    return treeWidget

def create_treeWidget_2():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)

    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item_0=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
    item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, "a")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, "b")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, "c")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, "1")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, "2")
    treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, "3")

    treeWidget.itemDropped.connect(buffer)
    treeWidget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(buffer)
    
    return treeWidget

def create_treeWidget_3():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
    treeWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    treeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    treeWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(False)

    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)

    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Header 0")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, "Header 1")
    treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, "Header 2")

    treeWidget.itemDropped.connect(buffer)
    treeWidget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(buffer)
    
    return treeWidget

def buffer():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    if counter==2: updateView(); counter=0        
    
def updateView():
    print('update')
    print('    update left:')
            
    iterator=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree2)

    while iterator.value():
        item=iterator.value()
        for column in range(item.columnCount()): print('        '+item.text(column))
        print()
        iterator+=1
            
    print('\n    update right:')
    iterator=QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree3)

    while iterator.value():
        item=iterator.value()
        for column in range(item.columnCount()): print('        '+item.text(column))
        print()
        iterator+=1

    print()

    print('-----')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle("fusion")
        tree1=create_treeWidget_1()
        tree2=create_treeWidget_2()
        tree3=create_treeWidget_3()
        tree1.show()
        tree2.show()
        tree3.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    except BaseException as e: print(e)
```

If an item gets moved from one tree too another the signal flow is

1. x.itemDropped.connect
2. x.models().rowsRemoved.connect -> correct output

If an item gets moved inside a tree the signal flow is

1. x.models().rowsRemoved.connect
2. x.itemDropped.connect -> correct output

To be honest I do not really know why the signal flow is not the same for both actions. But the second signal always returns the correct item distribution.

Comment: When moving an item from one tree to another, you have to emit the signal after the source tree internally removes the row. E.g. `event.source().model().rowsRemoved.connect(self.itemDropped.emit)`

Comment: @alec Nice hint. The solution is finally a combination of both, the custom signal and and the rowsRemoved event. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described you don't need to subclass. In Tree1 set the default drop action to `Qt.MoveAction` so it will move the item to the target instead of copy.

```
def create_treeWidget_1():
    ...
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    ...
```

And in Tree2 remove the line setting the drag drop mode to `InternalMove`, since that only allows drops from itself, and instead also set the default drop action to `Qt.MoveAction` to enable moving items within itself.

```
def create_treeWidget_2():
    ...
    treeWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
    treeWidget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
    treeWidget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    treeWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
    ...
```

Why the relevant drag/drop properties are needed or *not* needed for each tree widget:

**Tree1**

- `setDragEnabled(True)` is used so items can be dragged to Tree2.
- `setAcceptDrops(True)` is **NOT** used so items cannot be added to or moved within the view.
- `setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)` is used so items dragged and dropped into Tree2 are actually moved instead of copied.

**Tree2**

- `setDragEnabled(True)` is used to enable dragging its items.
- `setAcceptDrops(True)` is used to allow either internal or external items to be dropped within the view.
- `setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)` is used so internal items dropped within the view are moved instead of copied, mimicking `QAbstractItemView.InternalMove` but still allowing external drops.

You can disable the `Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled` flag for the new dropped items to prevent creating child items from them. In this case you *do* need to use the subclass.

```
class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super().dropEvent(event)
        if event.source() is not self:
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if self.dropIndicatorPosition() == self.BelowItem:
                item = self.itemBelow(item)
            elif self.dropIndicatorPosition() == self.OnViewport:
                item = self.topLevelItem(self.topLevelItemCount() - 1)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
```

And then use it for Tree2

```
def create_treeWidget_2():
    treeWidget=TreeWidget()
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. The OP says that for Tree1 "only sorting should be possible (no edit, move, copy etc)". Thus, for Tree1, it should only be possible to move items to Tree2; whereas for Tree2, it should be possible to both receive items and also rearrange them. In which case, your code must be adjusted so that in `create_treeWidget_1`, you do `treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(False)`, and in `create_treeWidget_2`, you do `treeWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro This does that. The `setAcceptDrops` method belongs to the QWidget class so it makes no difference whether you set it on the QTreeWidget itself or its viewport (and I just copied those lines from the OP). And by default the property is False.

Comment: As a matter of fact for convenience views the docs say to set it on the viewport. [Using convenience views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-convenience-views)

Comment: I was just trying to suggest your answer would be a little more precise if it stated that Tree1 must have accept-drops set to false, whilst Tree2 must have it set it to true (the specific widget is irrelevant). The OP isn't the only one who might look at your solution, so I think it's worth being more explicit on this general point (regardless of what the default settings are).

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah ok. I thought you meant my answer doesn't achieve the desired behavior. Since the only thing the OP was missing is the drop action, I only mentioned that. But I see your point, didactically it would be better to explain which are the necessary properties, so I will add that in.

Comment: Excellent - thanks. With hindsight, my first comment wasn't very well worded. Your answer covers everything perfectly now.

Comment: @elec: Thx for the answer and the explanation. Your suggested solution almost works. If I drop one item from tree1 to tree2 for some reason it becomes possible to drop the original items from tree2 inside the new items coming from tree1 -> create child items. This is even possible when setting the items of tree1 one to ```item_0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)``` during initialisation.

Comment: @alec: Hi alec, I updated my initial question. I have a new problem which is close nit to the initial one. I would be happy if you could help again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `dragMoveEvent` and `dragEnterEvent` methods in your QTreeWidget subclass, as well as the `dropEvent`, and accept events in those methods in order to receive the `dropEvent`. Otherwise the `dropEvent` will never be triggered.

Since your goal is to essentially move the item from one tree to another, inside of your drop event you can set the `dropAction` of the event to `Qt.DropAction.MoveAction` since the default is to simply copy it. Then you would need to take the mimedata from the event object and set add it to your TreeWidget's model.  And finally accept the DropEvent, so that it successfully removes the row from the source tree.

For Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex

class TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        action = Qt.DropAction.MoveAction
        mime = event.mimeData()
        row = self.topLevelItemCount()
        col = 0
        event.setDropAction(action)
        self.model().dropMimeData(mime, action, row, col, QModelIndex())
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
            event.accept()
        return super().dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
            event.accept()
        return super().dragEnterEvent(event)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer too. Your solution almost works too. For some reason it is not possible to move the item coming from tree1 upwards if they were dropped in tree2. They can only be moved downwards in the tree. Only the original items of tree2 can be moved up and down. Secondly the drop indicator for creating child items is shown. It is not possible to drop items inside other items but it is indicated which is a pitty.